# trap signal in bash initramfs fails to work

Tags: kernel, signals, initramfs, trap, initrd

inside `/init` bash script executed by the kernel in initramfs.img i need to send a signal to drop me to a rescue shell, so i have

```
trap "exec /bin/bash" SIGINT
```

but `ctrl+C` isn't effective.

First why the trap isn't working in initramfs stage? Is there otherway to achieve the same objective, to drop the user inside resuce shell during execution?

Comment: /init is usually not bash but busybox and you can check the busybox faq on the ctrl-c issue (won't help here though... rescue shell has to be deliberate, I guess)

Comment: no, it's bash i wrote it with my fingers.

Comment: The trap command won't fire while your shell is executing another command. It only fires between commands.

Comment: You might be better just starting a shell on a different TTY regardless. Kill it as you leave the initram process so it doesn't Heng around forever.

Comment: @roaima that is not true!

Comment: @Error, this in the man page for `bash` seems pretty clear to me: « _If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes._ »

Comment: @roaima i tested this, but seems to not be true, for example echo -e "trap 'exec /bin/bash'\ndd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null\n" > /tmp/trap.sh, then run /tmp/trap.sh, it will catch the signal!

Comment: but not in the initrmfs!